# Converting file to ASCII produces question marks

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, powershell-2.0

I am attempting to read in a text file, replace the contents of specific lines, and output the results again, ideally in the same format. The problem is that there are question marks (?) in the output file when there should not be and I have, thus far, been unable to resolve the problem.

I have tried:

```
Get-Content c:\test\file.xml -Encoding Ascii | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -like "replace") {
        Add-Content -Path "c:\test\output.xml" -Value $_.replace("replace","fixed") -Encoding Ascii
    } else {
        Add-content -Path "c:\test\output.xml -Value = $_ -Encoding Ascii
    }
}
```

and this results in certain accented characters being replaced with question marks.

I have also tried using streamreader and streamwriter with similar results:

```
$InputFile = @("c:\test\file.xml")
$OutputFile = "C:\test\output.xml"

#                                                 File         , Overwrite?, Encoding
$StreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("$OutputFile", "True", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)

foreach ($file in $InputFile) {
    #More info available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143457.aspx
    #                                                 File   , Text Encoding                  , Detect Encoding From Byte Order Marks (BOM)
    $StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("$File", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default, "False")
    while ($line = $StreamReader.readline()) {
        if ($line -like "*replace*") {
            $StreamWriter.Write("$line.replace(`"replace`",`"fixed`")")
        }
    }
    #$Line = $StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    #$StreamWriter.Write("$Line")
    #$StreamWriter.Flush()
}

$StreamReader.Close()
$StreamReader.Dispose()

$StreamWriter.Close()
$StreamWriter.Dispose()
```

I am not sure where to upload a copy of my file to, so that I can hyperlink it to here...any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure that would help a lot!

Comment: Update your question with an excerpt from your input file that still demonstrates the problem. Is the file actually ASCII encoded? Also, it appears to be an XML file, so you shouldn't be using string operations on it anyway.

Comment: If you are guessing at the file's encoding, you've lost the game before you started.